# django ForeignKey field should only select by category

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a ForeignKey field in my model and in `Django admin and` Django forms` when I display that field or in Django admin, I get all the field that in that model However, I only want to display selected fields in that dropdown, for example

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area_type_options = (('cc', 'Cost Center'), ('pc', 'Profit Center'),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=area_type_options)


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, unique=True)
    profit_center = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profit_center')
    cost_center = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cost_center')
```

I get to see all the records in the `cost_center` and all the records in the `profit_center` however I only want to see where `area_type` is cc to `cost_center` and where area type pc to `profit_center`

Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to do this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, unique=True)
    profit_center = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profit_center', limit_choices_to={'area_type': 'pc'})
    cost_center = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cost_center', limit_choices_to={'area_type': 'cc')
```